# Azure hosted On-prem build controller + VSO: Error TF400106: Failed to register the build service (Exception Message: Could not find service)

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm currently installing a TFS2013 SP4 build controller to run automated builds of my Visual Studio Online repository.

The readiness check is OK, but during the configuration I get an error and the following description:
**"TF400106: Failed to register the build service"**

In the log file I get the following information:

*Exception Message: **Could not find service '0000000d-0000-8888-8000-000000000000' from host'7786ddda-a6d4-4b3f-b512-18aa2ffb42b6'. Please ensure the service is registered with the Shared Platform Service. (type TeamFoundationServiceException)**
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)*

Any ideas / hints would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Which datacenter are you using? We're seeing the same error when talking to VS Online but only on the European one. US is working ok.

Comment: I am using the European datacenter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have rolled out the fix for this issue. Sorry for the disruption!

Comment: Thanks - the installation is now successful!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be currently issues :
[Microsoft Status](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/archive/2015/04/27/issues-with-visual-studio-online-4-27-investigating.aspx)